# How does one pull the value of a field into the html.tpl.php file

Tags: 7, views, theming

I populated a field on all nodes and all tax terms with a specific value pulled from a taxonomy list. 
The field name is the same on both nodes and tax terms. For example field_genre. 
How can I pull this value into the html.tpl.php file, on both nodes, tax pages and views pages?

Comment: why not use `node.tpl.php`?

Comment: I need to use the value in the <head> tag and not all of the pages referenced will be nodes.   Thanks!

Comment: You can do a `node_load` or `menu_get_item` in a `hook_preprocess_html` and then do a `field_get_items` within that routune to get a field value and then add that as say a body class or create a var ready for use in html.tpl.php.  Views pages will be a bit different, you'll have to load the views page in `hook_preprocess_html`.  For taxonomy pages, you can do something similar as for node but you'll have to load the term array first. This is not exactly trivial to do so you'd want a strong use case for having to jump hoops to do all this.

Comment: @Baybook The `<head>` tag.. is this for meta tags?

Comment: No, to use in a script tag.   Unfortunately,  I have a strong use case.  :)  Is there a place where I can get a good concrete example?

Comment: @Baybook - if you're adding a script tag, you'd want to do that with a preprocess function in a module or your theme's template.php, not in the html.tpl.php. I think you need to clarify your question and what it is exactly you need to do.